# Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over a field $F$. Prove the dependence of a set of vectors $\in V$ and reference request

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over a field $F$. Show that if $u_{1}, \dots, u_{n}, v_{1}, \dots, v_{n} \in V$ and $u_{1}, \dots, u_{n}$ are linearly independent, then there are only finitely many $c \in F$ such that $cu_{1} +v_{1}, \dots, cu_{n} + v_{n}$ are linearly dependent.

I try to tackle this problem by contradiction. Since $u_{i}$ are independent, if $\sum c_{i}u_{i} = 0$ then $c_{i} = 0.$ Suppose there are infinitely many $c \in F$ such that $\sum c_{i}[ cu_{i} + v_{i}] = 0$ for some tuple of $c_{i}$ not all zero. But this way seems futile?

Also, if possible, I would like to know this problem comes from which book, ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\det(cu_1+v_1, \dotsc, cu_n+v_n)$ is a polynomial in $c$ of degree $n > 0$ (with the leading coefficient being $\det(u_1,\dotsc, u_n) \neq 0$). This shows the result immediately.

Comment: Thanks so much, this approach is clever! Do you identify where the problem is from? Thanks. :)

Comment: I do not know. But this problem seems like a standard homework problem.

Comment: Really? A friend of mine discussed with me about this problem and I was stuck. My present working knowledge in linear algebra is quite not much and not proficient. I would like to find a good book, such as the book or books giving this problem. :)

Comment: Once you have heard about characteristic polynomials, you should be aware of the fact, that a determinant with a indeterminate is always a polynomial. And then the approach might be somehow clear. (You can even interpret this determinant as a characteristic polynomial of a suitable linear map, hence the set of $c$, such that the vectors are linear independent, as a set of eigenvalues, which is well known to be finite)